# ReactJS directly accessing parent function onClick refers infinite loop

Tags: function, loops, reactjs, prop

Today I've started building with React, but some results are somehow unexpected. So I some explanation would be nice. I've got the following component:

```
var QuestionItem = React.createClass({
    sendVote: function(e) {
        $(e.target).hasClass('up')
            ? this.props.onVoteUpdate(this.props.id, 'up')
            : this.props.onVoteUpdate(this.props.id, 'down');
    },


    render: function() {
        return (
            <li data-up={this.props.up} data-down={this.props.down}>
                <div className="votes">
                    <span className="up" onClick={this.sendVote}>+</span>
                    <span className="down" onClick={this.sendVote}>-</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        );
    }
});
```

When I click on the span I want to trigger the `onVoteUpdate` function in my parent component, but why is it necessary to create an extra function called (in my case) `sendVote`?

Because when I directly execute the function `onClick` as shown below:

```
<div className="votes">
    <span onClick={this.props.onVoteUpdate(this.props.id, 'up')}>+</span>
    <span onClick={this.props.onVoteUpdate(this.props.id, 'down')}>-</span>
</div>
```

it ends up in a infinite loop of console logs.

```
onVoteUpdate: function(question, state) {
    console.log(question);
    console.log(state);
});
```

Is this impossible, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I actually spent a good time yesterday with the same issue.

What is going on it's that you are calling `this.sendVote` when you assign it to the `onClick` event, this is causing the infinite loop, because each time you render, it re-renders because the state changed on this.sendVote and so on and so forth.

What you would rather do is bind `this.sendVote` to the `onClick` event.

This is what you want:

```
<span className="up" onClick={this.sendVote.bind(this)}>+</span>
<span className="down" onClick={this.sendVote.bind(this)}>-</span>
```

This way you are not calling `this.sendVote`, instead you are telling "Hey! everytime I click on this `<span>` i want to call `this.sendVote`"

Answer (score 2):

It probably helps to see how the JSX compiles:

```
<div className="votes">
    <span onClick={this.props.onVoteUpdate(this.props.id, 'up')}>+</span>
    <span onClick={this.props.onVoteUpdate(this.props.id, 'down')}>-</span>
</div>
```

compiles to:

```
React.createElement('div', { className: 'votes' },
    React.createElement('div', { onClick: this.props.onVoteUpdate(this.props.id, 'up') }, '+' ),
    React.createElement('div', { onClick: this.props.onVoteUpdate(this.props.id, 'down') }, '-' )
)
```

As you can see, you're not assigning the `onClick` handler to your method, you're actually assigning it to the *return value* of that method, since you're actually calling it during the render.

I would suggest breaking the behavior out into two methods:

```
var QuestionItem = React.createClass({
    sendUpVote: function () {
        this.props.onVoteUpdate(this.props.id, 'up');
    },

    sendDownVote: function () {
        this.props.onVoteUpdate(this.props.id, 'down');
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <li data-up={this.props.up} data-down={this.props.down}>
                <div className="votes">
                    <span className="up" onClick={this.sendUpVote}>+</span>
                    <span className="down" onClick={this.sendDownVote}>-</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        );
    }
});
```

Even though it might be a little more code, it's much clearer when reading the code what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="votes">
<span onClick={this.props.onVoteUpdate(this.props.id, 'up')}>+</span>
<span onClick={this.props.onVoteUpdate(this.props.id, 'down')}>-</span>
```

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <li data-up={this.props.up} data-down={this.props.down}>
            <div className="votes">
                <span className="up" onClick={()=>this.sendVote}>+</span>
                <span className="down" onClick={()=>this.sendVote}>-</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    );
}
```

});

This might work